# TikZ: What EXACTLY does the the |- notation for arrows do?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am currently trying to work out how the perpendicular arrows  work, and I fail.

Taking:

```
\draw [arrow] (node1) -- node[sloped, above] {Caption} (node1 |- node2.north west);
```

I suspected that the notation meant:
Draw an arrow from node 1, to the north-west corner of  node 2.
Make the arrow perpendicular to node 1.

Further attempts to draw arrows told me: No, that's not it. I have sadly failed to figure out what exactly the notation is supposed to be doing though! Is there any "explanation for dummies" that will lead me to understand what exactly

```
node1 |-
```

Is supposed to do?

Thanks!

Comment: This is clearly explained in section "13.3.1 Intersections of Perpendicular Lines" in the TikZ and PGF manual (page 141 in v 3.1.4a).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There are two different places to use `-|`/`|-`:

1. In a **coordinate** specification.

   This is what you have used, the general form is

   ```
   (a -| b)
   ```

   where `a` and `b` are named `node`s or `coordinate`s. This means the coordinate that is at the y-coordinate of `a`, and x-coordinate of `b`. Similarly, `(a |- b)` has the x-coordinate of `a` and y-coordinate of `b`.

   For example, the following code draws a horizontal arrow from `a` at `(0,0)` to `(1,0)`.

   ```
   \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (b) at (1,1);

   \draw [->] (a) -- (a -| b);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

   You can also use this as

   ```
   \coordinate (c) at (a -| b);
   ```

   and then `\draw [->] (a) -- (c);` does the same as the above.
2. As a **path** specification.

   This is used between two coordinates, in place of `--`.

   With `\draw [->] (a) -| (b);` the arrow goes horizontally from `a`, then vertically up to `b`. (And with `|-` it would be vertically first, then horizontally.)

   [image: output of code]

   ```
   \documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
   \coordinate (b) at (1,1);

   \draw [->] (a) -| (b);
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: The analogy between the coordinate and path specifications can be seen by noting that `\draw (a) -| (b);` is equivalent to `\draw (a) -- (a-|b) -- (b) ;`.

Comment: For anyone else who has issues deducing what exactly `-` and `|` mean: I define `|` as the vertical (y)-axis, and `-` as the horizontal (x)-axis. The notation now means "ignores the value of", i.e. `(a |- b)` means that "the y-axis of a and the x-axis of b is ignored", which in turn leads to the x value of a and the y value of b for that particular coordinate.

Answer (score 11):

If `a` is a coordinate/node at position `(a_x, a_y)` and
`b` is at `(b_x, b_y)` then

```
a |- b := (a_x, b_y) 

a -| b := (b_x, a_y)
```

They're just shorthands for combining the `x/y` coordinates of two points.

Comment: This is already mentioned in Torbjorn's answer no?

Comment: No, MathJax doesn't work. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths and linked questions.

Comment: The second line should be `a-|b := (b_x, a_y)`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit The user is not a frequent "flyer" of TeX.SE. I edited the answer directly.

Comment: @percusse Yes, this is already mentioned in Torbjørn's answer. Nevertheless, I think this straightforward notation could be useful, in some way.