# Right align of Tikz Node with different lengths

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, nodes

I want to align the node `GNU` (with the text "GNU C Library") right with the node `Userspace`.

I tried this with with the options `[anchor=north west, below=1cm of UserSpace]` but this doesn't work out.

Here the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Outer Frame
    \draw (0, -4) rectangle (14, 8);

    % Nodes
    \node (UserSpace) at(0.5,6) [rectangle, draw, anchor=south west, minimum width=13cm, minimum height=1cm, align=left,text width=13cm] {\textbf{User Space (Anwendung)}\\z.\,B. Office, Internet, Grafik, Bild-/Audio-/Video-Bearbeitung, etc.};

    \node (GNU)[rectangle, draw, anchor=north west, minimum width=6.5cm, minimum height=1cm, align=left,text width=6.5cm, below=1cm of UserSpace] {\textbf{GNU C Library}\\z.\,B. open, sbrk, exec, fopen, \dots};

    \node (GNU) [rectangle, draw, anchor=north west, minimum width=13cm, minimum height=1cm, align=left,text width=13cm, below=1cm of GNU] {\textbf{Kernel Space (Betriebssystem)}\\u.a. Dateisystem, Prozess- und Speichermanagement,\\ Ein- und  Ausgabe-Management};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

There is another little problem, I want a space between my nodes and the outer frame. Through the option `[text width = ...]` I can align my text left, but the length of the rectangles is not anymore the length I intended to have.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. You need the `anchor` setting *after* `below=..`, as `below` will also set the anchor, thus overwriting your setting.

Comment: Regarding the second problem, see options 1 or 2 in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124114/ (set `align=left` instead of `text width=..`).

Comment: Hey :)
It worked! Thanks :)
Is there a possibility to align now the Kernel Space 1cm below GNU but centered as UserSpace?

Comment: Regarding to your answer for the align=left - if I do so the linebreak is left aligned but not the whole text to the left of the rectangle :/

Comment: Remove `minimum width`.

Comment: Without minimum width the whole text is left aligned but the rectangle doesn't have anymore the length like User Space
Is there a way to set the length of the rectangle without affecting the alignment of the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not 100% clear to me what you want, is this the way you like it to be?

[image: output of code]

The key point for the text alignment, is to only set the `text width`. If you want the nodes to have at least a given width, use `minimum width`. If you want the node width to adapt to the content, while allowing line breaks with `\\`, use only `align=left`. But for this case where you want a specific width, setting the `text width` makes the most sense I think, you don't need `align` in addition here, as the text is left aligned by default.

I made some other changes as well:

- I defined a new style `box` that contains common settings for the nodes. Defining styles is a good way of making code more concise, and reduces the need for repetition, making it easier to change things. For example if you decide you want the node borders to be red with thicker lines, you just edit the definition of `box` to have `draw=red,thick`, instead of editing the options of every node separately.
- You wanted the middle node aligned with the right side of the upper node, so I set `below=UserSpace.south east`, i.e. the bottom right corner of `UserSpace`, followed by `anchor=north east`. Hence, the upper right corner of `GNU` is directly below the lower right corner of `UserSpace`.
- For the last node I set `below=of GNU.south -| UserSpace.south`. The `-|` notation is explained in [TikZ: What EXACTLY does the the |- notation for arrows do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do/401429#401429) In short, `GNU.south -| UserSpace` means the coordinate that has the y-component of `GNU.south`, and the x-component of `UserSpace`.
- Finally, I use the `fit` library to draw the surrounding frame at the end. Instead of drawing it first, and moving the nodes around, the nodes are placed first, and the frame drawn afterward. `fit=(UserSpace)(KernelSpace)` means that the node encompasses the `UserSpace` and `KernelSpace` nodes.

---

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style={
   draw,
   minimum height=1cm,
   text width=13cm
  }
]
% Nodes
\node [box] (UserSpace) {%
  \textbf{User Space (Anwendung)}\\
   z.\,B. Office, Internet, Grafik, Bild-/Audio-/Video-Bearbeitung, etc.};

\node [box,
       text width=6.5cm, % this overrwrites the text width of the style
       below=of UserSpace.south east,
       anchor=north east] (GNU)  {%
    \textbf{GNU C Library}\\
    z.\,B. open, sbrk, exec, fopen, \dots};

\node [box,
       below=of GNU.south -| UserSpace] (KernelSpace)  {%
   \textbf{Kernel Space (Betriebssystem)}\\
    u.a. Dateisystem, Prozess- und Speichermanagement,\\
    Ein- und  Ausgabe-Management};

\node [draw,fit=(UserSpace)(KernelSpace),inner sep=5mm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much!
Last question you used "box" is this like rectangle but always with left aligned text?

Comment: @B.Cak `box` is a style I defined, all it does for alignment is to set `text width`.

Comment: And what does "below=of GNU.south -| UserSpace.south" explicit -| mean?

Comment: @B.Cak I'm editing my answer now, will explain that.