# Is this kind of advanced positioning possible in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I am reproducing the following figure in TikZ:

[image: tikz advanced positioning example]

The upper right '}' curly brace and its full label is produced by the TikZ code that looks like:

```
\tikzstyle{ssbrace} = [decorate, decoration = {brace, amplitude = 6pt}, xshift = 8pt]
\tikzstyle{ssbracemath} = [midway, anchor = west, xshift = 4pt]
\draw [ssbrace] (\xvrr,\yGt) -- (\xvrr,\yPb)
    node [ssbracemath] (upperss) {$\in \mathbb{S}_d \oplus 0_{n_\text{sl}}$};
```

where `\xvrr`, `\yGt`, and `yPb` are macros that expand to strings such as e.g. `0.5/2+0.85/2+10pt/2-3pt`, meaning: sum half the unit width for the figure -with- half of 85% of the unit width of the figure -with- half of 10 points -and then subtract- 3 points. The complex syntax is because the various components of the string come from more primitive macros that define numerous adjustable parameters. Assume

```
\newcommand{\xvrr}{0.5/2+0.85/2+10pt/2-3pt}
\newcommand{\yGt}{0.1+10pt}
\newcommand{\yBp}{0.5+10pt}
\newcommand{\yyPc}{1+0.1+10pt}
\newcommand{\eqmarg}{2pt}
```

for sake of the example.

What I would then like to do is render the `\mathbb{S}_{n_\text{P}}` "S" part of the lower label so that its *x* center is equal to the *x* center of the upper label (node `upperss`) and with a parameteric *y* coordinate of `\yyPc`. That is,

```
\draw (upperss.center,\yyPc) node [anchor=center] (lowerss) {$\mathbb{S}_{n_\text{P}}$};
```

although the above raises the error "Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `upperss' (in 'upperss.center'). \draw (upperss.center,\yyPc)" among others, hence my attempts at intuiting TikZ syntax have evidently failed.

With the `lowerss` node in place, I'd finally like to render the 'in' (`\in`) for the lower label centered between the rightmost extent of the lower brace and the leftmost extent of `lowerss`. For this, I attach an empty node named `lowerssbrace` to the lower brace, and then invoke

```
\draw (lowerssbrace.east/2+lowerss.west/2,\yyPc) node [anchor=center] {$\in$};
```

I don't know whether this will work either. In fact, my knowledge of what permutations of which kinds of coordinate arithmetic TikZ supports is limited to "It seems to understand what both `(1/2+1/2,1-1/2)` and `(lowerss.center)` mean as coordinates."  Whether or not it can mix relative and absolute dimensions, mix named coordinates and dimensions, or perform basic arithmetic such as `lowerssbrace.east/2`: I have no idea, although my hopes are high.

Note also that the rightmost labeled arrow relies on coordinates `(upperss.center,upperss.south+\eqmarg)` and `(upperss.center,lowerss.north-\eqmarg)`, hence I also have cases where named coordinates are summed with absolute dimensions.

Everything else in the figure is working as expected.

**Is what I'm trying to accomplish here possible to do in TikZ? If so, what is the required syntax?**

Many thanks for any assistance. You will have saved me days of spelunking through documentation, assuming this is even possible.

Comment: yes, it is possible. with some effort and pations, using `matrix` and `positioning` libraries. for details read `tikz & pgf` manual. request "do-it-for-me here aren't very welcome. show us what you try so far.

Comment: for starting point search for answers/questions with tag `tikz-matrix`.

Comment: You can probably use the `let` operation, see chapter 14.15 in the TikZ manual, which lets you access the x- and y-components of a coordinate. Note also that when you mix numbers and units, the unitless numbers are seen as `pt`.  Try for example `\tikz \draw [->] (0.5,0) -- (0.5+10pt,0);` which doesn't do what it seems you think it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, note that if you mix unitless numbers and lengths in a coordinate specifications, the unitless numbers are read as lengths in `pt`, as described in the manual section 13.2 *Specifying coordinates*. Hence, `1+0.1+10pt` becomes 11.1pt, and thus the following code makes an arrow pointing left:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\yyPc}{1+0.1+10pt}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (1,0) -- (\yyPc,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

There are various methods that can be applied.

To get the x-component of one node and the y-component of another, the easiest way is to use perpendicular coordinates, which I explain in [TikZ: What EXACTLY does the the |- notation for arrows do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do/401429#401429).

To place a node midway between two other nodes, you can do

```
\path (a) -- node{this is halfway between a and b} (b);
```

To place a node a given distance from another node, one method is to use relative coordinates,

```
\path (lowerssbrace) ++(20pt,0) node {20pt right of lowerssbrace};
```

You could also study the features of the `calc` library, described in section 13.5 *Coordinate calculations* of the TikZ manual.

If you want more specific advice, please add a complete example to your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\yyPc}{1+0.1+10pt}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (upperss) {};
\node [draw, red] (lowerssbrace) at (-2,0) {};

\draw (upperss.center |- 0,\yyPc) node (lowerss) {$\mathbb{S}_{n_\text{P}}$};

\path (lowerssbrace |- lowerss) -- node {$\in$} (lowerss);

\node at ($(lowerssbrace) + (20pt,0)$) {a};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was able to make everything work with these tricks. Many thanks.