# Node positioning inside tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am composing a `tikz` drawing consisting of two nodes `a` and `b`. I want to insert node `c` such that `c.x=b.x` and `c.y=a.y`. See below the code snippet-

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[style=help lines] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
  \node (a) [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20]   at (1, 1) {Rectangle A};
  \node (b) [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20] at (4, 4) {Rectangle B};
  \node (c) [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20]  at (4, 1) {Rectangle C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Below is the generated diagram-

[image: genered diagram]

Notice that I have manually mentioned the coordinates of node `c`.

**How to use `let` or any other command from `calc` to provide the coordinates such that `c.x=b.x` and `c.y=a.y`?**

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I'm a little bit confused.... do you mean`c.x=b.x` and `c.y=a.y`?

Comment: @Bobyandbob: yeah. you are right. sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if I understand correctly it must answer your question

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[style=help lines] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
  \node (a) [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20]   at (1, 1) {Rectangle A};
  \node (b) [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20] at (4, 4) {Rectangle B};
  \node (c) [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20]  at (b|-a) {Rectangle C};

  \node[rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20](d) at ($(a)!0.3!(b)$) {rect D};


  \node (e) [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20]  at (a|-b) {Rectangle E};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much... I have used `|-` and `-|` for positioning lines such as turning by 90 degrees... Can you please provide a brief explanation of the code you provided? I would like to know about `!0.3!` supported by `calc`. Previously I have used `!0.5!` for midpoint calculation but this seems more powerful

Comment: ($ (a)! xx! (b) $) designates the point at xx% between (a) and (b), xx can take values between 0 and 1 as well as greater than 1, we will go beyond (b) or less than 0 and then the point will be before (a)

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[style=help lines] (0, 0) grid (5, 5);
  \node (a) [rectangle, draw, fill=red!20]   at (1, 1) {Rectangle A};
  \node (b) [rectangle, draw, fill=green!20] at (4, 4) {Rectangle B};
  \node (c) [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20]  at (b|-a) {Rectangle C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much... The operator `|-` used with nodes is new to me. thought, I have used it for drawing lines in the past! Can you please provide a brief explanation of the code?

Comment: @RaviJoshi it is described on page 38 of the current pgfmanual (section 2.15 Specifying Coordinates). The first listing using it is on page 44 (section 2.21 Adding Text).

Comment: @RaviJoshi See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do/401429#401429

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Thank you very much. I have used `|-` and `-| `with `draw` however this was the first time, I got to know that it can be used with In a coordinate specification for a `node`.