# node positioning involving shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

This script

```
\documentclass\[tikz,border=5pt\]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node\[draw, align =    center,
    minimum height = 1.5cm,
    text width = 1.5cm\]
  (a) at (0, 0){a};
  \node\[draw\](b) at (a.north east)\[anchor= north west\]{b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

delivers the expected output where node `b` is positioned relative no node `a`:

[image]

Nice!

However, adding a shape (`rounded rectangle`) to node `a` disrupts this harmony:

```
\node[draw, align = center,
    minimum height = 1.5cm,
    text width = 1.5cm]
  (a) at (0, 0)[rounded rectangle]{a};
```

[image]

The expected output is:

[image]

where the red line shows an imagined border around node `a`.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want, you could do

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, align = center,
    minimum height = 1.5cm,
    text width = 1.5cm]
  (a) at (0, 0)[rounded rectangle]{a};
  \node[draw](b) at (a.east |- a.north)[anchor=north west]{b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The main question is what you want to achieve. It is obvious that the anchor `north east` is not at a corner, simply because a `rounded rectangle` has no corners. So I "invented" a corner. `(a.east |- a.north)` is precisely an imaginary corner of a rectangle around the `a` node,

It is of course also possible to let the `b` node touch the boundary of `a`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, align = center,name path=rr,
    minimum height = 1.5cm,
    text width = 1.5cm]
  (a) at (0, 0)[rounded rectangle]{a};
  \node[opacity=0,overlay](phantomb) at (a.east |- a.north)[anchor=north west]{b};
  \path[name path=aux] (phantomb.south west) -- ++(-1,0);
  \draw[name intersections={of=rr and aux}] node[draw](b) at (intersection-1)
  [anchor=south west]{b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are other possibilities, really depends on what you precisely want to achieve.

Addendum: relative positioning of two such shapes. I do not know what precisely you are after, but here is a possibility.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc,intersections,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw, align = center,name path=rr,
    minimum height = 1.5cm,
    text width = 1.5cm]
  (a) at (0, 0)[rounded rectangle]{a};
  \node[opacity=0,rounded rectangle,overlay](phantomb) at (a.east |- a.north)[anchor=north west]{b};
  \path[name path=aux] (phantomb.south west) -- ++(-1,0);
  \draw[name intersections={of=rr and aux}] 
  let \p1=($(phantomb.south west)-(phantomb.south -| phantomb.west)$) in
  node[draw,rounded rectangle](b) at ([xshift=\x1]intersection-1)
  [anchor=south west]{b};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Added `overlay` to prevent the phantom nodes from enlarging the bounding box.

Comment: This is not what I want. node `b` should remain in the same location as in the first figure, imagining a rectangular border drawn enclosing the rounded rectangle.

Comment: @Viesturs Yes, this is what my updated answer does. `(a.east |- a.north)` is precisely an imaginary corner of a rectangle around `a`.

Comment: `|-` signifies an intersection point?

Comment: @Viesturs Sort of. It says: take the `x` coordinate of `a.east` and the `y` coordinate of `a.north`. This is explained in detail in [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/121799).

Comment: What if node `b` itself is drawn with a `rounded rectangle`? How to set the anchor?

Comment: @Viesturs I added something. The idea is to measure the mismatch between `(phantomb.south west)` and `(phantomb.south -| phantomb.west)` and use the distance to shift the node. Of course, here are tons of possibilities, touch vs. not touch etc., but all of them can be addressed this way, I think

Comment: I love the phantom box trick.  I'll have to remember that.

Comment: @A.Ellett Thanks but I certainly do not deserve any credit for that. This is essentially how the `visible on` from aobs (`texdoc aobs`) works.

Comment: Thanks for point that out.  I didn't know about `aobs`.  Looks very interesting.  Thank you for sharing that.