# Precise placement of arrow anchors

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment

I have a (TikZ) diagram with several "blocks" of text connected by arrows.  For reasons the (centers of the) blocks are not precisely horizontally aligned, but I'd still like my vertical arrows to be perfectly, well, vertical.  Example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle, draw] (a) at (0,0) {Some rather long text};
  \node[rectangle, draw] (b) at (.5,-2) {Even more text};
  \path[->] (a) edge (b);
  \path[red, ->] (a.315) edge (b.130);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Instead of the black arrow, I'd prefer the red one which I've created by fiddling around with stupid numbers.  Hence:

Is there a way to create, automatically, instead of the black arrow-between-centers, an arrow which is (1) perfectly vertical and (2) intersects the original arrow roughly at its center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or, if you want the arrow to be in the center,

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle, draw] (a) at (0,0) {Some rather long text};
  \node[rectangle, draw] (b) at (.5,-2) {Even more text};
  \path (a) -- (b) coordinate[midway] (aux);
  \draw[->] (a.south -| aux) -- (b.north -| aux);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You guys are amazing: this is precisely what I wanted.

Comment: +1: What is the `aux` node for?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It is midway between a and b and placed solely for calculation.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner This is a trick to find out (what Ti*k*Z thinks is) the middle between the two nodes, which then will determine the horizontal position of the arrow.

Comment: @marmot and @TeXnician, thanks to both for the reply. Now I realize, that `|-` forced a 90° angle. I missed that and was wondering ;).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I guess the best explanation for what `|-` and `-|` do can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/121799).

Comment: @marmot I see, that is good information ("In a coordinate specification.").

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the horizontal and vertical position in terms of nodes.

[image: vertical arrow]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle, draw] (a) at (0,0) {Some rather long text};
  \node[rectangle, draw] (b) at (.5,-2) {Even more text};
  \draw[->] (b|-a.south) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice (+1)... I think that the OP woyld like to use `anchor=east` too in order to not calculating manually the horizontal alignment. So, `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={rectangle,draw,anchor=east}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[mynode] (a) at (0,0) {Some rather long text};
  \node[mynode] (b) at (0,-2) {Even more text};
  \draw[->] (b|-a.south) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` would be an easier way.