# Minipage, make figures float at the same level

Tags: floats, minipage

I have the code here

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{sidecap}  %required for side captions

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
     \subfigure[A1]{\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{universe}\label{perf_11}}
      \subfigure[A2]{\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{universe}\label{perf_33}}
     \subfigure[A3]{\includegraphics[width=.31\textwidth]{universe}\label{episodes}}
     \caption{It is really a beautiful picture captured by an awesome Telescope}\label{performance}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
     \subfigure[B1]{\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{universe}\label{33_ab_per}}
     \subfigure[B2]{\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{universe}\label{33_ab_ep}}
     \caption{Universe}\label{33_sg_per_abla}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But the figures above do not float at the same level, how can I make it floating the same level?

Comment: You could use `floatrow` or `adjustbox` (see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/476533/121799)). And I recommend using `subcaption` instead of `subfigure`.

Comment: Have you tried with `[t]` instead `[b]` in both minipages?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\usepackage{sidecap}  %required for side captions

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
  \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.6\textwidth,valign=T}
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\label{perf_11}
      \caption{A1}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\label{perf_33}
      \caption{A2}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.32\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\label{episodes}
      \caption{A3}
     \end{subfigure}
     \caption{It is really a beautiful picture captured by an awesome Telescope}\label{performance}
  \end{adjustbox}
  \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=0.4\textwidth,valign=T}
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\label{33_ab_per}
      \caption{B1}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.475\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth]{example-image-duck}\label{33_ab_ep}
      \caption{B2}
     \end{subfigure}
     \caption{Universe.}\label{33_sg_per_abla}
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]