# How to align coordinates vertically and horizontally in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, coordinates

I have points with irrational coordinates, because I'm mixing polar and Cartesian coordinates. I'd like to specify a coordinate as the x-value of one thing and the y-value of another thing.

In this specific example, I want the two lines on the left to have the same left endpoints.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (left) at (155:2);
    \coordinate (top) at (65:2);
    \coordinate (bottom) at (245:2);
    \coordinate (right) at (335:2);

    \coordinate (leftEdge) at ($ (left) + (-2,0) $);
    \coordinate (bottomEdge) at ($ (bottom) + (0,-2) $);

    \path[draw=black] (left) -- (top) -- (right) -- (bottom) -- cycle;
    \path[draw=blue] (left) -- (leftEdge);
    \path[draw=black] (bottom) -- (bottomEdge);
    \path[draw=red] (bottom) -- ++(-2,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I think there's a way to do this with something like `(leftEdge.x,bottom.y)`, but I've been unsuccessful in getting it to work.

[image]

How can I get the red edge to go as far left as the blue edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you all you need to do is to say `\path[draw=red] (bottom) -- (bottom-|leftEdge);`. [This great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/121799) provides you with a very nce discussion of this syntax.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (left) at (155:2);
    \coordinate (top) at (65:2);
    \coordinate (bottom) at (245:2);
    \coordinate (right) at (335:2);

    \coordinate (leftEdge) at ($ (left) + (-2,0) $);
    \coordinate (bottomEdge) at ($ (bottom) + (0,-2) $);

    \path[draw=black] (left) -- (top) -- (right) -- (bottom) -- cycle;
    \path[draw=blue] (left) -- (leftEdge);
    \path[draw=black] (bottom) -- (bottomEdge);
    \path[draw=red] (bottom) -- (bottom-|leftEdge);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Follow-up question: suppose I want to specify a direction and a line to end on.  For example, draw a line at 225 degrees from `(right)`, and make it long enough to reach the bottom border of the image.  Is there a similarly quick way to do that?

Comment: @PiFisher Yes, with the `calc` library, which you are already loading : `\draw[purple] (right) -- (intersection cs:first
 line={(right)--($(right)+(225:3)$)},second
 line={(bottomEdge)--($(bottomEdge)+(3,0)$)});`.