# Macro returning a length depending on current chapter

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, koma-script

I am writing a document using scrbook and I have defined a custom chapter style where I draw a large chapter number using tikz:

```
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=south east, yshift=1.2cm, xshift=\textwidth,
          inner sep=0, outer sep=0]{%
        \fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont%
        \textcolor{laccentcolor}{\thechapter}%
    };
    % alignment line
    \draw[thin] (current page text area.north east)
        -- (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

The chapter number is supposed to align to the right of the text area, but it doesn't because of the whitespace around the number that is part of the character:

[image]

The distance to the right border is different for each number. To achieve perfect alignment I would like to adjust the positioning of the chapter number on a per-chapter basis. My idea to achieve this was to define a command that returns a different length depending on the current value of `\thechapter`, and then use this command to define the `xshift` of the chapter number:

```
\newcommand*{\chapteroffset}{%
\IfEndWith{\thechapter}{1}{\textwidth+15mm}{%
\IfEndWith{\thechapter}{2}{\textwidth+5mm}{%
\IfEndWith{\thechapter}{3}{\textwidth+6mm}{%
\textwidth+0mm%
}}}%
}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=south east, yshift=1.2cm, xshift=\chapteroffset,
          inner sep=0, outer sep=0]{%
        \fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont%
        \textcolor{laccentcolor}{\thechapter}%
    };
    % alignment line
    \draw[thin] (current page text area.north east)
        -- (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

I've tried multiple different ways to achieve this, but all of them until now have resulted in some kind of endless loop where my document doesn't finish building. I suspect the reason is that I am not using the right way to return a dimension from an if expression.

How can I return a dimension from a macro that changes with the current chapter? Mind that it also needs to work for non-integer numbers in the appendix. Alternatively, how can I achieve the look in the picture in some different way?

This is a current MWE of my status:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=15mm, DIV=8]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{
    headings=twolinechapter,
    chapterprefix=false,
    numbers=noenddot
}

\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    positioning}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{calc}

\definecolor{laccentcolor}{HTML}{d3d3d3}


\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

% Macro that determines the per-chapter offsets.
% If I use this definition, the document will not finish building.
% \newcommand*{\chapteroffset}{%
% \IfEndWith{\thechapter}{1}{\textwidth+15mm}{%
% \IfEndWith{\thechapter}{2}{\textwidth+5mm}{%
% \IfEndWith{\thechapter}{3}{\textwidth+6mm}{%
% \textwidth+0mm%
% }}}%
% }

% returning a fixed length from the macro like this works
\newcommand*{\chapteroffset}{\textwidth+5mm}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\LARGE}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=south east, yshift=1.2cm, xshift=\chapteroffset,
          inner sep=0, outer sep=0]{%
        \fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont%
        \textcolor{laccentcolor}{\thechapter}%
    };
    % alignment line
    \draw[thin] (current page text area.north east)
        -- (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{10cm}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm short in time, so only a note: The commands of `xstring` are not expandable. So you cannot use them in a context, where you need the expanded result of the test. So it maybe it would be better to define a `\setoffset`-command that sets a length `\chapteroffset` and use that command before you need the value, e.g., before the `tikzpicture`. Also: `\thechapter` does not need to result in a string only (but in your example it should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just store the shifts in an array, which you could use. Since you are loading `tikzpagenodes`, I would also suggest making use of that package.

```
\documentclass[BCOR=15mm, DIV=8]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{
    headings=twolinechapter,
    chapterprefix=false,
    numbers=noenddot
}

\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    positioning}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{calc}

\definecolor{laccentcolor}{HTML}{d3d3d3}


\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}


% returning a fixed length from the macro like this works
\newcommand*{\chapteroffset}{\textwidth+5mm}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\LARGE}

\def\chaplengths{{11mm,5mm,6mm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\coordinate (mychapanchor-\arabic{chapter});
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylength}{\chaplengths[\arabic{chapter}-1]}
    \node[anchor=south east,xshift=\mylength,
          inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
          at ([yshift=1.2cm]mychapanchor-\arabic{chapter}-| current page text area.east){%
        \fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont%
        \textcolor{laccentcolor}{\thechapter}%
    };
    % alignment line
    \draw[thin] (current page text area.north east)
        -- (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{10cm}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a workable solution, although I would have to hard code which chapters belong to the appendix. I am not familiar with some of the syntax you used: `\coordinate (mychapanchor-\arabic{chapter});` Does this just define a new name for the coordinate per chapter or does the dash imply subtraction? `([yshift=1.2cm]mychapanchor-\arabic{chapter}-| current page text area.east)` What does the vertical bar `|` mean here? Is this some way of specifying x and y from different coordinates that I don't know yet?

Comment: @toster I am using the array syntax which is explained on p. 999 of the pgfmanual. That is, I store the lengths in `\chaplengths` by saying `\def\chaplengths{{11mm,5mm,6mm}}` (note the double `{` `}`) and then access them with `\pgfmathsetmacro{\mylength}{\chaplengths[\arabic{chapter}-1]}` (the `-1` is because the first element has array index `0`).

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't the syntax I was unclear on. Please read my comment again.

Comment: @toster Sorry, I indeed didn't read carefully. Yes, this defines new coordinates. Strictly speaking this is not necessary but I find that cleaner. What may, however, be important, is to first set some anchor and *then* use an overlay picture. (I was actually a bit surprised that it worked so well in your code, but would definitely fix it.) And a very nice discussion on `-|` and `|-` can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/121799. Sorry again!

Comment: Thanks, I just found this syntax in the pgfmanual. It could have saved me a lot of typing in the past. I used to use `\let` expressions to do stuff like this.

Comment: @toster I guess you are not the first one making this experience. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\int_case:nnF` from `expl3`:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=15mm, DIV=8]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{
    headings=twolinechapter,
    chapterprefix=false,
    numbers=noenddot
}

\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    positioning}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage{xparse}

\definecolor{laccentcolor}{HTML}{d3d3d3}


\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

% Macro that determines the per-chapter offsets.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\chapteroffset}{}
 {
  \textwidth+
  \int_case:nnF { \int_mod:nn { \value{chapter} } { 10 } }
   {
    {1}{11mm} % shift for last digit 1
    {2}{5mm} % shift for last digit 2
    {3}{6mm} % shift for last digit 3
   }
   {1mm} % shift for all other cases
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\LARGE}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=south east, yshift=1.2cm, xshift=\chapteroffset,
          inner sep=0, outer sep=0]{%
        \fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont%
        \textcolor{laccentcolor}{\thechapter}%
    };
    % alignment line
    \draw[thin] (current page text area.north east)
        -- (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{10cm}}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to take care of the appendix add a “variable command”. Perhaps `scrbook` has a built-in conditional for testing whether it is in the appendix part. If so, it shouldn't be difficult to use it instead of the home-made `\ifappendix`.

```
\documentclass[BCOR=15mm, DIV=8]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{
    headings=twolinechapter,
    chapterprefix=false,
    numbers=noenddot
}

\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    positioning}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage{xparse}

\definecolor{laccentcolor}{HTML}{d3d3d3}


\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

% Macro that determines the per-chapter offsets.
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\chapteroffset}{}
 {
  \textwidth+
  \ifappendix\offsetforchapter\else\offsetforappendix\fi
 }
\newif\ifappendix
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\offsetforchapter}{}
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \int_mod:nn { \value{chapter} } { 10 } }
   {
    {1}{11mm}
    {2}{5mm}
    {3}{6mm}
   }
   {1mm} % all other cases
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\offsetforappendix}{}
 {
  \int_case:nnF { \value{chapter} }
   {
    {1}{11mm} % offset for A
    {2}{5mm}  % offset for B
    {3}{6mm}  % offset for C
   }
   {1mm} % all other cases
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\LARGE}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=south east, yshift=1.2cm, xshift=\chapteroffset,
          inner sep=0, outer sep=0]{%
        \fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont%
        \textcolor{laccentcolor}{\thechapter}%
    };
    % alignment line
    \draw[thin] (current page text area.north east)
        -- (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{10cm}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
\lipsum[1-2]

\appendix\appendixtrue

\chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on marmot and egreg's answers, this is what I ended up using:

```
\newif\ifappendix

\def\chaplengths{{11mm,6mm,7mm,2.5mm,7mm,5mm,6mm,7mm,6.5mm}}
\def\applengths{{4mm,8.5mm,6mm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\coordinate (mychapanchor-\arabic{chapter});
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylength}{\ifappendix\applengths[\arabic{chapter}-1]\else\chaplengths[\arabic{chapter}-1]\fi}
    \node[anchor=south east,xshift=\mylength,
          inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
          at ([yshift=1.2cm]mychapanchor-\arabic{chapter}-| current page text area.east){%
        \fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont%
        \textcolor{laccentcolor}{\thechapter}%
    };
    % alignment line
    \draw[thin] (current page text area.north east)
        -- (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[BCOR=15mm, DIV=8]{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{
    headings=twolinechapter,
    chapterprefix=false,
    numbers=noenddot
}

\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc,
    positioning}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{calc}

\definecolor{laccentcolor}{HTML}{d3d3d3}


\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}


\addtokomafont{chapter}{\scshape\LARGE}

\newif\ifappendix

\def\chaplengths{{11mm,6mm,7mm,2.5mm,7mm,5mm,6mm,7mm,6.5mm}}
\def\applengths{{4mm,8.5mm,6mm}}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\coordinate (mychapanchor-\arabic{chapter});
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylength}{\ifappendix\applengths[\arabic{chapter}-1]\else\chaplengths[\arabic{chapter}-1]\fi}
    \node[anchor=south east,xshift=\mylength,
          inner sep=0, outer sep=0]
          at ([yshift=1.2cm]mychapanchor-\arabic{chapter}-| current page text area.east){%
        \fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont%
        \textcolor{laccentcolor}{\thechapter}%
    };
    % alignment line
    \draw[thin] (current page text area.north east)
        -- (current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{10cm}}

\begin{document}
% 1
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

% 2
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

% 3
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

% 4
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

% 5
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

% 6
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

% 7
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

% 8
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

% 9
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]

    \appendix\appendixtrue

% A
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]
% B
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]
% C
    \chapter{A Fancy Chapter Name to Test the Formatting}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```