# Tikz node with a fixed and variable coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

In Tikz: how can I place a node A relative to the position of node B but with one coordinate fixed? Or put differently, how can one make two nodes share either the x or the y coordinate? For example, I would like to have box2 above box1 but not 0.3cm above box1, but let's say at y=3cm, here:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (box1) [box] {};
\node (box2) [box, above of = box1, node distance = .3cm] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\node (box2) [box] at (box1|-0,3) {};` See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/121799 for more details on the `|-` and `-|` syntax.

Comment: Just tried both answers - both work. Thank you!

Comment: No, my approach doesn't generally work. @marmot's approach works in every case.

Comment: In both approaches it is to be noted that the first node is placed at `(0,0)`, so @JouleV does work, too. Please notice that in your MWE you are using deprecated syntax. You will be much better off if you load `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` and say something like `\node (box2) [box, above=.3cm of box1] {};`. (The `3d` library is not used here.)