# Connecting two nodes from the same mother node horizontally

Tags: diagrams, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

I am trying to create a diagram where one node connects to two nodes horizontally. I have attached the image of the diagram I want. However, I am having trouble moving the **d** node upward so that the arrow to **e** can flow through. Also, I can't seem to put **e** node a bit further to the right. In addition, I can't manually position the start point of the arrow as well. Right now, the two arrows coming out from node **c** are overlapped with each other.

This is my current minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm, text centered, minimum height=1.5cm, text width=3cm, very thick, draw=black, fill=white]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) [startstop] {\textsf{{\normalsize A}}};
    \node (b) [startstop, right=1cm of a] {\textsf{b}};
    \node (c) [startstop, right= 1cm of b] {\textsf{c}};
    \node (d) [startstop, right = 1cm of c]  {\textsf{d}};
    \node (e) [startstop, right = 1cm of d] {\textsf{e}};

    \draw [arrow] (a) -- (b);
    \draw [arrow] (b) -- (c);
    \draw [arrow] (c) -- (d);
    \draw [arrow] (c) -- (e);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the diagram I want to draw:

[image: This is the diagram I want to draw]

I would greatly appreciate it if anyone can help me on this!!!!

Comment: I think you need `above right = 1cm of c` for the node `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=2cm, text
centered, minimum height=1.5cm, text width=3cm, very thick, draw=black,
fill=white},
arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,]
    \node (a) [startstop] {A};
    \node (b) [startstop, right=1cm of a] {b};
    \node (c) [startstop, right= 1cm of b] {c};
    \node (d) [startstop, right = 1cm of c,yshift=1.25em]  {d};
    \node (e) [startstop, right = 1cm of d,yshift=-2.5em] {e};

    \draw [arrow] (a) -- (b);
    \draw [arrow] (b) -- (c);
    \draw [arrow] (c.east|-d) -- (d);
    \draw [arrow] (c.east|-e) -- (e);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comments:

- to move the nodes vertically, just use `yshift`;
- `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, so I replaced it by the corresponding `\tikzset` command;
- if you want all texts sans serif, it is easier to add `font=\sffamily`;
- if you add `tikz` to the options of `standalone` this will load `tikz` *and* make it a standalone environment;
- the syntax `|-` and `-|` is nicely explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/121799) and is used to make sure the connections are horizontal;
- I removed all libraries you do not use;
- it might make sense here to use chains, or not.

Comment: You won for some seconds... lol

Comment: @Sigur Sorry, didn't know... (my crystal ball got stolen...)  ;-)

Comment: but my solution wild not be so good as yours.

Comment: @marmot Thank you so so much!!!! This is exactly what I want!

Comment: @Sigur I guess judgement is up to the voters...

Comment: @Shao you're welcome!