# opamp node to line connection artifact

Tags: circuitikz

I have a slight visual disturbance on the connection between the nodes of the opamp and the lines connecting to it.

[image]

Maybe it does not get better, or do i have to adjust some line thickness?
Thanks for your help!

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\ctikzset{voltage/distance from node=.2}% defines arrow's distance from nodes
\ctikzset{voltage/distance from line=.02}% defines arrow's distance from wires
\ctikzset{voltage/bump b/.initial=.1}% defines arrow's curvature
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw
(0,0) node[ocirc] (A) {}
(0,3) node [ocirc] (B) {}
(11,0) node[ocirc] (C) {}
(11,3.5) node[ocirc] (D) {}
(3,3) node[circ] (E) {}
(6,3) node[circ] (F) {}
(10,3.5) node[circ] (O) {}
(10,5) node[circ] (OT) {}
(8,3.5) node[op amp] (opamp) {}

(B) to [open,v=$u_e(t)$] (A)
(D) to [open, v^=$u_a(t)$] (C)

(A) -- (C)

(B) to[R, l=$R_1$] (E) to[R,l=$R_2$] (opamp.+)
(F) to[C,l=$C_1$] (6,0)

(E) -- (3,6) to[C, l=$C_2$] (10,6) -- (O) -- (opamp.out)
(opamp.-) -- (6,4) -- (6,5) -- (OT)
(O) -- (D)
(opamp.+) node[left] {}
(opamp.-) node[left] {}
(opamp.out) node[right] {}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{2nd Order Low Pass}
\label{fig:lowpass}
```

\end{figure}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi! Which PDF viewer are you using? A lot of this cases are due to PDF viewer antialiasing algorithms (for example: `okular` is horrible, `evince` is better). Try to print it too. Anyway, I'll check as soon as I can...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to adjust a coordinate, `opamp.-` isn't at exactly y = 4, so the line isn't horizontal. To avoid explicit x-y coordinates, you can do for example

```
(opamp.-) -- (opamp.- -| F) |- (OT)
```

The `-|`/`|-` syntax is described in [TikZ: What EXACTLY does the the |- notation for arrows do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do/401429#401429)

The same goes for the other one, you need to somehow make sure that `F` and `opamp.+` is at the same y-coordinate. One way of doing that is to set up the diagram differently, placing `F` relative to `opamp`, instead of using explicit coordinates. You can place everything relative to other things if you like, for example:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\ctikzset{voltage/distance from node=.2}% defines arrow's distance from nodes
\ctikzset{voltage/distance from line=.02}% defines arrow's distance from wires
\ctikzset{voltage/bump b/.initial=.1}% defines arrow's curvature

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw
  node[op amp] (opamp) {}
  node[circ, right=of opamp] (O) {}  
  node[circ, left=of opamp.+] (F) {}
  node[ocirc, right=of O,label=right:D] (D) {}
  node[circ, left=3cm of F] (E) {}
  node[circ, above=of O] (OT) {}
  node[ocirc,left=3cm of E] (B) {}
  node[ocirc, below=3cm of B] (A) {}
  (A -| D) node[ocirc] (C) {}
  % define a few helper coordinates, used below when drawing the connections
  (F |- A) coordinate (tmpC1)
  coordinate[above=of OT] (tmpC2)
  coordinate[left=of opamp.-] (tmpF)

(B) to [open,v=$u_e(t)$] (A)
(D) to [open, v^=$u_a(t)$] (C)

(A) -- (C)

(B) to[R, l=$R_1$] (E) to[R,l=$R_2$] (opamp.+)
(F) to[C,l=$C_1$] (tmpC1)

(E) -- (E |- tmpC2) to[C, l=$C_2$] (tmpC2) -- (O) -- (opamp.out)
(opamp.-) -- (tmpF) |- (OT)
(O) -- (D)
(opamp.+) node[left] {}
(opamp.-) node[left] {}
(opamp.out) node[right] {}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I got an error with the option "right=of", etc.

Comment: @jotagah Did you add `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`? (Forgot to mention that specifically, but it's in my code example.)

Comment: @Torbørn, I had used QTiKz to "run" the circuitikz code only. Using your full example I got an error: "Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `west' (in 'west')". Maybe anything wrong with my TeXLive 20019 installation.

Comment: @jotagah That sounds a bit odd, I would expect that QTikZ uses the same TeX distribution as any other LaTeX editor you have. It works fine for me with TL2019.

Comment: How could i place second opamp so that its input aligns with an existing node?

Comment: @Rico Try to set the anchor of the opamp to whatever part you want to align with the other node, and positioning it relative to that node. E.g. `anchor=+, right=of foo`.

Comment: @Torbjorn This `node[op amp,anchor=+, right=of stage2in,yscale=-1] (opamp2) {}` is not working

Comment: @Rico I can't test right now, but what does ”not work“ mean?

Comment: It does not move the opamp up, so the alignment would be correct. It seems that the ancher does not have a effekt.

Comment: @Rico Oh sorry, I made a mistake. The anchor setting has to be placed after the right=, because the latter sets the anchor.

Comment: Thanks this is working!  `node[op amp, right= 2cm of stage2in, anchor=+, yscale=-1] (opamp2) {}`

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501080/38080) is correct, but also notice that the PDF viewer can play a role in this. The different antialiasing algorithms can show different things. For example, using Torbjørn's code, you have at the same zoom (150%):

1. In `okular` (which is great for other things, but... notice the lines and the capacitors)

[image: output from okular]

2. In `evince` (which I can't use with `vimtex` with back reference, though renders better on my display)...

[image: output from evince]