# Latex Equals Symbols Greyed Out... Bug?

Tags: debugging

[image: Every equals (=) symbol looks like a minus (-) because the lower half is greyed out. Does anyone know why this happens? Very confusing to look at and have no idea why it's doing this?]

Every equals (=) symbol looks like a minus (-) because the lower half is greyed out. Does anyone know why this happens? Very confusing to look at and have no idea why it's doing this?

Comment: Can you provide code that replicates this? What about zooming in... does it show the equal sign then?

Comment: If there's a bug, it's likely with your PDF viewer. What are you using to view your output and have you tried changing the zoom level?

Comment: This looks like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501089/38080 - antialiasing problem by the viewer. It seems like your viewer mishandle subpixel elements...