# Graph whit Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill, scoping, clip

I wanto to draw this graph whit Tikz:

[image]

I have this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]                                                                                          
 \begin{scope}                                                                                                          
% Relleno gris superior e^x                                                                                             
                   clip \fill [color=gray!40, domain=-1.2:1.2, variable=\x]                                             
                   (-1.2, 0)                                                                                            
                   -- plot ({\x}, {exp(\x)})                                                                            
                   -- (-1.2, 3.29) -- cycle;                                                                            
                   % % Relleno blanco inferior de e^-x                                                                  
                   clip \fill [color=white, domain=-1.2:1.2, variable=\x]                                               
                   (-1.2, 0)                                                                                            
                   -- plot ({\x}, {exp(-\x)})                                                                           
                   -- (1.2, 0) -- cycle;                                                                                
                    \end{scope}                                                                                         
                    \begin{scope}                                                                                       
                   % Relleno gris inferior  e^x                                                                         
                   clip \fill [color=gray!40, domain=-1.2:1.2, variable=\x]                                             
                   (-1.2, 0)                                                                                            
                   -- plot ({\x}, {exp(\x)})                                                                            
                   -- (1.2,0) -- cycle;                                                                                 
                   % Relleno blanco inferior de e^-x                                                                    
                   clip \fill [color=white, domain=-1.2:1.2, variable=\x]                                               
                   (-1.2, 3.29)                                                                                         
                   -- plot ({\x}, {exp(-\x)})                                                                           
                   -- (1.2, 3.29) -- cycle;                                                                             
                 \end{scope}                                                                                            
                   % Funciones e^x                                                                                      
                   \draw[-] plot[domain=-1.2:1.2] (\x,{exp(\x)});                                                       
                                      % Funciones e^-x                                                                  
                   \draw[-] plot[domain=-1.2:1.2] (\x,{exp(-\x)});                                                      
                   % coordinate grid                                                                                    
                   \draw[->] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};                                                            
                   \draw[->] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};                                                            
                   \draw (0,1) node[ right] {{\tiny $1$}};                                                              
                 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Is wrong: [image]

Comment: Do a search on the site for "fillbetween". You'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: You can "accept" the provided answer since it seems to solve solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! From your picture I didn't know which of these you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,%
    p1/.style={insert path={plot[domain=-1.2:1.2] (\x,{exp(\x)})}},
    p2/.style={insert path={plot[domain=-1.2:1.2] (\x,{exp(-\x)})}}]
 % fills
 % upper
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[p1] -| cycle;
  \fill[gray!40,p2] |- cycle;
 \end{scope}
 % lower
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[p1] -- (1.2,0) -| cycle;
  \fill[gray!40,p2]  -- (1.2,0) -| cycle;
 \end{scope}
 % plots
 \draw[->] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};                                                            
 \draw[->] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};                                                            
 \path (0,1) node[right,font=\tiny] {$1$};        
 \draw[semithick,p1];                                                       
 \draw[semithick,p2];          
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,%
    p1/.style={insert path={plot[domain=-1.2:1.2] (\x,{exp(\x)})}},
    p2/.style={insert path={plot[domain=-1.2:1.2] (\x,{exp(-\x)})}}]
 % fills
 % upper
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[p1] -| cycle;
  \fill[gray!40,p2] |- cycle;
 \end{scope}
 % lower
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[p1]  |- cycle;
  \fill[gray!40,p2]   -| cycle;
 \end{scope}
 % plots
 \draw[->] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};                                                            
 \draw[->] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};                                                            
 \path (0,1) node[right,font=\tiny] {$1$};        
 \draw[semithick,p1];                                                       
 \draw[semithick,p2];          
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I think this is very similar to what you had in mind but if you use

```
 clip \fill
```

the `clip` does not have any effect. Also it is perhaps simpler to store the paths that get reused in styles like `p1` and `p2` here.

You actually do not need a clip.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,%
    p1/.style={insert path={plot[domain=-1.2:1.2] (\x,{exp(\x)})}},
    p2/.style={insert path={plot[domain=-1.2:1.2] (\x,{exp(-\x)})}}]
 % fill
 \fill[gray!40,p1]  --  plot[domain=-1.2:1.2] (\x,{exp(-\x)});
 % plots
 \draw[->] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right]{$x$};                                                            
 \draw[->] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};                                                            
 \path (0,1) node[right,font=\tiny] {$1$};        
 \draw[semithick,p1];                                                       
 \draw[semithick,p2];          
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The other version works analogously.

Comment: Thanks cat, I didn't know that way to fill. Where can I find more information about that?

Comment: @ArnoldFernández In the pgfmanual.

Comment: I found an 800 page text.

Comment: @ArnoldFernández Then you have found an old version. The [current version of the pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) has 1318 pages. The `\fill` command is already used on the title page. It may be thought of as a synonym of `\path[fill]`. Its basic usage is explained in section **2.13 Filling and Drawing**. The perhaps more important points of this answer are the clips, the [`|-` and `-|` syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/194703), and the `insert path` key, though.