# Bezier curve for a loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, bezier

I would like to enhance the output given by the following code : see the picture below where the end of the arrow is lower and the loop "bigger".

To do this I need a better control of the Bezier curve and also I would like to add a minus sign inside the loop.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{vNiceMatrix}[first-row]
    u & v  \\
    x & x'  \\
    y & y'
    \CodeAfter
    \tikz \draw [red,->]
        (1-1.east) .. 
            controls (2-2.south east) 
            and
            (2-1.south west)
        .. (1-2.west) ;
\end{vNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the `in` and `out` keys (and make the matrix a bit bigger so that the annotations do not clash with the matrix entries).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{vNiceMatrix}[first-row,columns-width=1.5em]
    u & v  \\
    x & x'  \\
    y & y'
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \path (1-1.east) -- node[below=0.35em,red,inner sep=0pt] (minus) {$-$} (1-2.west);
     \draw [red,->]
        (1-1.east) to[out=0,in=30]  (minus.south east) 
        to[out=-150,in=-30]  (minus.south west)
        to[out=150,in=180] (1-2.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}           
\end{vNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or maybe also make sure that the arrow attaches at the same vertical position.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{vNiceMatrix}[first-row,columns-width=1.5em]
    u & v  \\
    x & x'  \\
    y & y'
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \path (1-1.east) -- node[below=0.35em,red,inner sep=0pt] (minus) {$-$} (1-2.west);
     \draw [red,->]
        (1-1.east) to[out=0,in=30]  (minus.south east) 
        to[out=-150,in=-30]  (minus.south west)
        to[out=150,in=180] (1-1.east-|1-2.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}           
\end{vNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or even more symmetric.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

$\begin{vNiceMatrix}[first-row,columns-width=1.5em]
    u & v  \\
    x & x'  \\
    y & y'
    \CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}
     \path (1-1.east) -- node[below=0.35em,red,circle,inner sep=1pt] (minus) {$-$} (1-2.west);
     \draw [red,->] let \p1=($(minus.east)-(minus.center)$) in 
        (1-1.east) to[out=0,in=150]  (minus.60) 
        arc[start angle=60,end angle=-240,radius=\x1] 
        to[out=30,in=180] (1-1.east-|1-2.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}           
\end{vNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why does `(1-1.east-|1-2.west)` do the trick for the vertical position ?

Comment: @projetmbc The syntax `(1-1.east-|1-2.west)` means "take the y component of `1-1.east` and the x component of `1-2.west`). It is very nicely described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429

Comment: Thanks for this clarification and the link.

Comment: I use ($(1-1.east) + (0.05,0)$). How can I acheive a similar thing but to the arrow ?

Comment: @projetmbc Sorry, I do not understand this comment. How are you using `($(1-1.east) + (0.05,0)$)` (which can be translated to `([yshift=0.5mm]1-1.east)`)? (Or are you looking for `...([yshift=-0.5mm]1-1.east) coordinate (aux)  ... (aux-|1-2.west)`?)

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks ! I want that the start and the end of the arrow to be less near to the text.

Comment: @projetmbc You can use the keys `shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt`, say.

Comment: Ok. I note this way to do the right thing.