# What do "-to" and "pre=moveto" do in TikZ arrows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-node

On page 61/1318 TikZ manual there is an example which I simplify and change it a little bit to create the following picture:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\draw [->,-to, thick, decorate,
\draw [shorten >=1mm,-to, thick, decorate, red,
decoration={snake,amplitude=.4mm,segment length=2mm, pre=moveto, pre length=1mm, post length=2mm}]
(0,0) -- (3,0)
node [above=1mm,align=center,midway, text width=3 cm]
{
replacement of\\
the \textcolor{black}{capacity}\\
by \textcolor{black}{two places}
};
\draw [|-|] (2.8,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [|-|] (0,0) -- (.1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have these questions:

1. What does `-to` do?
2. What does `pre=moveto` do?
3. Although `post length=2mm` according to the measurement using `\draw [|-|] (2.8,0) -- (3,0);` it looks post length is shorter.
4. `shorten >=1mm` is applied where and how it works with pre and post lengths?

Comment: When you decorate a path, you can have the decoration start a little later to start by drawing a straight line on a few millimetres and then decorate it properly. `moveto` means to go to a certain place without drawing or colouring, it's a **move**.  Here `pre=moveto, pre length=1mm` specifies that the first millimetre nothing will be drawn, the decoration does nothing and nothing will be drawn the first millimetre of the path.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: `-to` is a now obsolete syntax initiated with the first versions of TikZ like `1.18` and to is the name of a predefined arrow.  From now on, this is replaced by `>`.

Comment: Thanks @AndreC, so -to is replaced by > ? I put > instead of -to and it did not work.

Comment: `-to` is now replaced by `->`

Comment: `shorten` is now obsolete, but no other command is equivalent in version 3.1 so it is still used. You can find its definition in the `1.18` manual which can be downloaded here [tikz manual 1.18](https://home.adelphi.edu/~tfoguel/tikzpgfmanual.pdf)

Comment: @AndréC Where does it say that `shorten` is obsolete?

Comment: Regarding the `post length`, to get that accurate, you need a `segment length` appropriate to fit an integer number of "waves" in the available part of the path, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552354/ for a similar case.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Just as `tikzstyle` is no longer documented in manual 3.0.1a or 3.1.5b, `shorten` is no longer documented. Both are **still functional and undocumented**, so the maintainer considers them obsolete. Otherwise, one would find the documentation for `shorten` in the latest manual and would not need to read the old manuals to understand their syntax.

Comment: @AndréC Ehm, page 211 in the manual for 3.1.5b? Or page 1121 for the lower-level `\pgfsetshorten...`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It's good news that this has been re-documented, it had disappeared from the 3.0.1a manual. A few years ago I had asked for this part to be put back, I see it has been done. Good. I'm very pleased.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is customary here that there is only one question at a time. Nevertheless, I will **answer only the first two questions**, and I urge you to ask the other question again, which alone deserves further development.

## First question : What does `-to` do?

In [TikZ and pgf Manual for version 1.18](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf), on page 322, we learn that `-to` is an arrow.

[image: manual-1.18]

Looking at its shape, we can see that it is the **Computer Modern Rightarrow** as shown on page 207 of the 3.1.5b manual. I quote:

> Instead of a `<arrow tip kind name>`, you may also provide the name of
> a so-called *shorthand*. Shorthands look like normal arrow tip kind
> names and, indeed, you will often be using shorthands without noticing
> that you do. The idea is that instead of, say, **Computer Modern
> Rightarrow** you might wish to just write **Rightarrow** or perhaps
> just **To** or even just **>**.

## Second question: What does `pre=moveto` do?

When you decorate a path, you can have the decoration start a little later to start by drawing a straight line on a few millimetres and then decorate it properly. **moveto** means to go to a certain place without drawing or colouring, it's a **move**. Here `pre=moveto, pre length=1mm` specifies that the first millimetre nothing will be drawn, the decoration does nothing and nothing will be drawn the first millimetre of the path.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={font=\small\ttfamily, black, right}]
  \draw[thick, red] (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
    node {1.1 init with "thick, red"};

  \draw[thick, red, shorten >=1mm, yshift=-.5cm] 
    (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
    node {1.2 add "shorten >=1mm"};
  \draw[|-|, yshift=-.4cm] (2.9, 0) -- node[above, font=\tiny] {1mm} (3, 0);

  \draw[thick, red, shorten >=1mm, -to, yshift=-1cm] 
    (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
    node {1.3 add arrow "-to"};

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-2cm]
    \draw[thick, red] (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
      node {2.1 the same as 1.1};

    \draw[thick, red, decorate,
      decoration={snake},
      yshift=-.5cm,
    ] (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
      node {2.2 add "decorate, decoration=\{snake\}"};

    \draw[thick, red, decorate, 
      decoration={snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2mm},
      yshift=-1cm,
    ] (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
      node {2.3 add "decoration=\{..., amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2mm\}"};

    \draw[thick, red, decorate,
      decoration={
        snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2mm, 
        pre length=1mm, post length=2mm
      },
      yshift=-1.5cm,
    ] (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
      node {2.4 add "decoration=\{..., pre length=1mm, post length=2mm\}"};
    \draw[|-|, yshift=-1.4cm] (0, 0) -- node[above, font=\tiny] {1mm} (.1, 0);
    \draw[|-|, yshift=-1.4cm] (2.8, 0) -- node[above, font=\tiny] {2mm} (3, 0);

    \draw[thick, red, decorate,
      decoration={
        snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2mm, 
        pre length=1mm, post length=2mm, pre=moveto
      },
      yshift=-2.0cm,
    ] (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
      node {2.5 add "decoration=\{..., pre=moveto\}"};
    \draw[|-|, yshift=-1.9cm] (0, 0) -- node[above, font=\tiny] {1mm} (.1, 0);
  \end{scope}

  \begin{scope}[yshift=-5cm]
    \draw[thick, red, shorten >=1mm, -to, decorate,
      decoration={
        snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2mm, 
      }
    ] (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
      node {3.1 combine 1.3 and 2.3, not good};

    \def\x{\ \ \ \ }
    \draw[thick, red, shorten >=5mm, -to, decorate,
      decoration={
        snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2mm, 
      },
      yshift=-.5cm,
    ] (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
      node[yshift=-.6cm, align=left] {
        3.2 combine 1.3 and 2.3 and \\
        \x  use "shorten >=5mm" to show the real problem:\\
        \x decoration is not shortened and a line is drawn \\
        \x from real end (3, 0) to shortened end (2.5, 0).
    };
    \draw[|-|, yshift=-.4cm] (2.5, 0) -- node[above, font=\tiny] {5mm} (3, 0);

    \draw[thick, red, shorten >=5mm, -to, decorate,
      decoration={
        snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2mm,
        post length=6mm, pre=moveto
      },
      yshift=-2.2cm,
    ] (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
      node {3.2' add "decoration=\{..., post length=6mm, pre=moveto\}", ok};

    \draw[thick, red, shorten >=1mm, -to, decorate,
      decoration={
        snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=2mm, 
        pre length=1mm, post length=2mm, pre=moveto
      },
      yshift=-2.7cm
    ] (0, 0) -- (3, 0)
      node {3.3 combine 1.3 and 2.5, ok};
    \draw[|-|, yshift=-2.6cm] (2.9, 0) -- node[above, font=\tiny] {1mm} (3, 0);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, very nice Looks like [visualTikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/visualtikz)