# 0 above the Pascal-triangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

The Pascal triangle for binomial coefficients starts with `1` in line 1 and goes on with `1 1` in line 2, `1 2 1` in line 3, and so on.

The answers to this question

[Pascal's triangle in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/pascals-triangle-in-tikz)

show how one may write up solutions in tikz.

Here is the adapted version which I prefer:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\x}
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\binom{factorial(\x)/(factorial(\y)*factorial(\x-\y))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\shift{\x/2}
        \node[xshift=-\shift cm] at (\x,\y) {\pgfmathprintnumber\binom};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I write up a variant which has `0` in the first line, `1` in the second line, `1 1` in the third line and thereafter goes on as the usual Pascal's triangle?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112704/discussion-on-question-by-sapiens-0-above-the-pascal-triangle).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just add

```
\node at (-1,0) {0};
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
\node at (-1,0) {0};
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
{
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\x}
    {
        \pgfmathsetmacro\binom{factorial(\x)/(factorial(\y)*factorial(\x-\y))}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\shift{\x/2}
        \node[xshift=-\shift cm] at (\x,\y) {\pgfmathprintnumber\binom};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a small alternative to @Torbjorn's answer (a trick he taught me [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/545466/binomial-tree-in-pgfplots) ) to avoid using (annoying IMHO, `\pgfmathsetmacro`), include the variables to evaluate directly in the loop.

More details in pfg manual v3.1.5.b p1003, section 89 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=-90]
\node at (-1,0) {0};
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,3}
{
 \foreach [evaluate ={
           \binom = factorial(\x)/(factorial(\y)*factorial(\x-\y));
           \shift = \x/2 ;
           }] \y in {0,...,\x}
    {\node[xshift=-\shift cm] at (\x,\y) {\pgfmathprintnumber\binom};}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Where is documented `evaluate ={...}` as you used it in the manual?

Comment: @AndréC PGF manual 3.1.5.b p. 1003. section 89 Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement

Comment: The problem is that it looks more like the syntax of the `math` library on page 704 since it says `evaluate={...}`. But you haven't loaded this library. And yet with the syntax of this library it works.  The syntax of the foreach is not the same as the one you wrote. Maybe it's a syntax initiated on an old version of tikz?

Comment: @AndréC Etrange ! Trying a `\pgfversion`, it tells me     
tikz.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
pgf.sty    2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b) which does not seem too old.

Comment: No, it's not strange, there's a lot of code in the latest manual that comes from old manuals and is not documented. And since the code you used is not documented in this manual I wonder which manual it is documented in. It's classic look here: [What do “-to” and “pre=moveto” do in TikZ arrows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/555655/138900)

Comment: @AndréC I use this one https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf.I must be missing something.

Comment: I too use the 3.1.5b manual, but it contains old code that is documented in older manuals. `evaluate={...}` is used since manual 3.0 but according to my research is not clearly documented in any manual!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111343/discussion-between-jet-and-andrec).