# 3 pgfplots plots, all in the same beamer frame

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, resize, tikzscale, scale

I have a beamer frame inside which I want to include a figure composed of 3 independent plots, like this:

[image: 3 plots]

**Please note that each one of these has completely different axis `domain` *and* `unit vector ratio*`.** So, if I am not wrong, `groupplot` is not suitable for this situation.

I created the following `.tikz` file:

```
% myPlot.tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[domain=-5:5,unit vector ratio*=2 1]
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-7cm]
\begin{axis}[domain=-1:3,unit vector ratio*=1 2]
\addplot {-x};
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[yshift=-7cm,xshift=8cm]
\begin{axis}[domain=-2:10,y domain=0:4,unit vector ratio*=1 0.8]
\addplot {x*x};
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And inside my beamer frame I have

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,graphicx,siunitx,tikzscale}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{geometry,xcolor}    
\geometry{paperwidth=148mm,paperheight=96mm}
\useoutertheme[width=20mm]{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Algebra and Geometry}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=230pt]{myPlot.tikz}
\end{figure}
An additional line of text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

But I get an error

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@x
```

What is the correct way of creating such figure?

I am really having hard time at it, and would really like to solve this issue soon.

Desired output is

[image]

(Made artificially with Windows Paint)

I also tried

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{194pt}
{
\input{myPlot.tikz}
}
```

Bit it stretches the figure:

[image: not good]

Needless to say, the real figure I am working on is composed of 3 much more complicated `axis` environments, one of which is a `surf` and the other is a curve in the 3d space..

I guess that the problem starts with the `scope` environment that I defined that calls for a an `x` and `y` shift specified in cm's.

I think that the best way is to let TeX decide what should be `xshift` and `yshift`, and to be calculated according to the figure `width` and `height` inside `includegraphics`.

This where I am asking for you help.

##### Update:

I just learned that one can do

```
% myPlot.tikz
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth,height=194pt}

\begin{axis}[domain=-5:5,unit vector ratio*=2 1]
% rest of file..
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But still I  `shift`ed the `begin{axis}` in the `x` and `y` direction, by some values in cm, after a few trial and errors, until I got a satisfactory output.

I wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: Considering what you say at the end there, I'd consider using three separate `tikzpicture`s,  defining an appropriate size for each `axis`, e.g. `width=\linewidth, height=0.3\linewidth` for the first one, without involving `tikzscale`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manual shifts, you can add a `name` to the first `axis`, and place the other two axes using the available anchors described in section 4.19 *Alignment options* of the `pgfplots` manual (page 374 in manual for version 1.18.1).

The `-|` notation is a way to get the x-position of one coordinate, and the y-position of another, cf. [TikZ: What EXACTLY does the the |- notation for arrows do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do/401429#401429)

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{geometry}    
\geometry{paperwidth=148mm,paperheight=96mm}
\useoutertheme[width=20mm]{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Algebra and Geometry}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  unit vector ratio*=2 1,
  width=0.5\linewidth,
  name=topaxis]
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  domain=-1:3,unit vector ratio*=1 2,
  height=0.4\linewidth,
  at={(topaxis.south west |- topaxis.outer south west)},
  anchor=north west,
  ]
\addplot {-x};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
  domain=-2:10,y domain=0:4,unit vector ratio*=1 0.8,
  height=0.4\linewidth,
  at={(topaxis.south east |- topaxis.outer south east)},
  anchor=north east]
\addplot {x*x};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

An additional line of text.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Once again you come up with a clever solution. Thanks very much!