# coordinates on the x axis of tikz plot are incorrectly displayed

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis, grids

I am trying to draw a function as well as a shaded grid on the same axes. Although I use a step size of 1cm in the grid between -3 and 0, the xticks, as well as the shaded region look misplaced. how can I solve this? thanks

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=right,  
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel={$t$},
    ylabel={$x$},
    %position spatial axes label on top of the axis
    every axis y label/.style={
    at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
    anchor=south,
},  xtick={-7, -6, -5,  -4,  -3, -2 ,-1},
%    xticklabels={$-7$, $-6$, $-5$,  $-4$,  $-3$, $-2$ ,$-1$},
%    ytick={0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1},
    domain=-7:0,
    xmin=-7, xmax=0,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.1,
    samples=500,
]
    \addplot+[mark=none,color=black] {e^(x/2.75)};
\draw[step=1cm,color=gray!50,opacity=0.5] (-3,0) grid (0,1);
\filldraw [fill=gray, draw=black,opacity=0.5]
-- (-3,0)
-- (-3,0.2)
-- (-2,0.2)
-- (-2,0.4)
-- (-1,0.4)
-- (-1,0.6)
-- (0,0.6)
-- (0,0)
-- cycle;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates inside an `axis` environment are not the same as those outside it. The way it works is that `pgpflots` sets the size of the axis, and then scales things so that the range (defined either by the data or `xmin`/`xmax`) fits inside that width.

If you set

```
scale only axis,
width=7cm, height=5.5cm
```

things might look better.

`scale only axis` is required because `pgfplots` leaves 45pt of space in both x- and y-directions for axis labels. Hence, if you set `width=345pt`, the width of the axis box alone will be 300pt. `width=7cm` is because your x-range is from -7 to 0, and you have a tick every 1 axis unit. `height=5.5cm` is because your y-range is from 0 to 1.1 with ticks every 0.2 axis units.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=right,  
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel={$t$},
    ylabel={$x$},
    %position spatial axes label on top of the axis
    every axis y label/.style={
       at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
       anchor=south,
    },
    xtick={-7, ..., -1},
    ytick={0,0.2,...,1.1},
    domain=-7:0,
    xmin=-7, xmax=0,
    ymin=0, ymax=1.1,
    samples=50,
    scale only axis,
    width=7cm, height=5.5cm
]
\addplot+[mark=none,color=black] {e^(x/2.75)};

\draw[step=1cm,color=gray!50,opacity=0.5] (-3,0) grid (0,1);
\filldraw [fill=gray, draw=black,opacity=0.5]
(-3,0) -| (0,0.6) -| (-1,0.4) -| (-2,0.2) -| cycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I simplified the filling code a bit using https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do/401429#401429