# diagram composing function

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to make a typical composing-function diagram and I've saw a few posts, but I cannot make it yet as I'd like. In this picture I show what I attempt to make
[image]

But the most I got is

[image]

As you can see, I used empty nodes for the broken line, but not exactly worthy. I leave my code here so you can help me with its edition. I must confess I'm basic user in Latex and 100% newbie in Tikz, so any guide you use is welcome.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
    \node(1) {$C$};
    \node(2) [right of=1] {$C_{0}$};
    \node(3) [right of=2] {$P_{0}$};
    \node(4) [right of=3] {$P$};
    \node(5) [right of=4] {$f^{*}(P)$};
    \node(11) [below of=1] {};
    \node(15) [below of=5] {};
    \draw[->](1) to node {$\tau_{c}^{-1}$}(2);
    \draw[->](2) to node {$l^{-1}$}(3);
    \draw[->](3) to node {$\tau_{-1}$}(4);
    \draw[->](4) to node {$f^{*}$}(5);
    \draw[-](1) to node {}(11);
    \draw[->](15) to node {}(5);
    \draw[-](11) to node {$f = \tau_{c}^{-1} \circ l^{-1} \circ \tau_{-1} \circ f^{*}$}(15);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome on TeX.SE. Take a look at [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425/tikz-what-exactly-does-the-the-notation-for-arrows-do)

Comment: @JeT Thanks, I'm reading it. Been myselft such a newbie, a whole manual is more useful, but thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were almost at it.

First version with too much vertical space:
[image: pic]

Second one with reduced vertical space:
[image: V2]

You can adjust everything by paying attention to the code. The important part is `--++(0,-1)` here which draws a vertical line of 1cm length.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, auto]
    \node(1) {$C$};
    \node(2) [right of=1] {$C_{0}$};
    \node(3) [right of=2] {$P_{0}$};
    \node(4) [right of=3] {$P$};
    \node(5) [right of=4] {$f^{*}(P)$};
    \node(11) [below of=1] {};
    \node(15) [below of=5] {};
    \draw[->](1) to node {$\tau_{c}^{-1}$}(2);
    \draw[->](2) to node {$l^{-1}$}(3);
    \draw[->](3) to node {$\tau_{-1}$}(4);
    \draw[->](4) to node {$f^{*}$}(5);

    % \draw[->] (1) --++ (0,-2) -| node[pos=0.25] {$f = \tau_{c}^{-1} \circ l^{-1} \circ \tau_{-1} \circ f^{*}$} (5); %(old version)

    \draw[->] (1) --++ (0,-1) -| node[pos=0.25,below] {$f = \tau_{c}^{-1} \circ l^{-1} \circ \tau_{-1} \circ f^{*}$} (5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's close indeed! How can I make the vertical lines shorter? There's too much empty space at my diagram. And  how to make the composition label to appear below the line?

Comment: I'll edit my answer as requested.

Comment: Thanks you both. Once you have a comand (or optional arguments for it), making little changes on it helps a lot to see how it works.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative possibility where are employ `tikz` libraries `arrows.meta` (for arrows), `chains` (for make chain of nodes), `positioning` (for distances between nodes) and `quotes` )for edge lables):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 8mm and 12mm, 
  start chain = A going right,
every edge/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb}
                        ]
\foreach \i in {C, C_0, P_0, P, f^{*}(P)}
    \node[on chain=A] {$\i$};
\coordinate[below=of A-5]  (A-6);
\draw   (A-1) edge["$\tau_{c}^{-1}$"]   (A-2) 
        (A-2) edge["$l^{-1}$"]          (A-3) 
        (A-3) edge["$\tau_{-1}$"]       (A-4) 
        (A-4) edge["$f^{*}$"]           (A-5)
        (A-1) |- (A-6)  node[pos=0.75, below] 
                        {$f = \tau_{c}^{-1} \circ l^{-1} \circ \tau_{-1} \circ f^{*}$} 
        (A-6) edge (A-5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The code is quite short with a normal displaymath environment, using `\xrightarrow`  and  `pstricks`(more precisely with `pst-node`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node} 

\begin{document}

  \[ \rnode{C}{C} \xrightarrow[\rule{3em}{0pt}]{\tau_c^{-1}} C_0 \xrightarrow[\rule{3em}{0pt}]{l^{-1}}P_0 \xrightarrow[\rule{3em}{0pt}]{\tau_{-1}}P 0\xrightarrow[\rule{3em}{0pt}]{f*}\rnode{F}{f^*(P)}
  \psset{linewidth=0.5pt, angle = -90, arm=0.8cm, arrowinset=0.15, nodesepA=3pt, linejoin=1}
  \ncbar{->}{C}{F} \nbput{f^*\circ \tau_{-1}\circ l^{-1}\circ \tau_c^{-1}}
  \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yeap, I thought at `\xrightarrow` at first, but as I had no idea to manage the large line, I start to search info and tought it would be easier with just one enviroment than mixing them.

But it's a nice approach anyway and can be useful in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment. The advantage of pstricks is that it can be used without any problem  within math environments.