# Shorter way of obtaining curved angle with intersections

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

Consider the following (inspired by [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/34551)):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (1,1);
    \draw [->, red] (a) -| (b);
    \draw [->] (a).. controls (a -| b) .. (b); % Shorter way to do this?
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

it gives:

[image]

Is there a shorter way of obtaining the second type of path, more curved?

Comment: That... looks pretty short already. Otherwise maybe the only way is to define your own macro

Comment: Do the existing answers help you? What do you have in mind when it comes to shorter?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, @Qrrbrbirlbel, I have accepted an answer. I meant "shorter to type", but the answers I have received have opened interesting new options :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean with "more curved". Something like this?

**Edit (1):**
Considered @Paul Gaborit comment:

**Edit (2):**
Added use of `arrows.meta` and `bending` libraries:

[image]

Draw second line as line with `curved corners=<radius>`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                bending}
\tikzset{> = {Straight Barb[bend]},
         }

\begin{document}\small
With default radius value:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (1,1);
    \draw [->, red] (a) -| (b);
    \draw [->, rounded corners] (a) -| (b); 
    \end{tikzpicture}

With radius of 10mm:

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (1,1);
    \draw [->, red] (a) -| (b);
    \draw [->, rounded corners=10mm] (a) -| (b); 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "_more curved_" = `rounded corners=.9cm` ?

Comment: @PaulGaborit, it can be. See edited answer.

Comment: Add `\tikzset{curved corners/.forward to=/tikz/rounded corners}`... :-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit, thank you for suggestion. However, I'm not familiar with its use.

Comment: It was just a joke. The `curved corners` key does not exist.

Comment: @PaulGaborit, :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 6):

Not sure exactly what "shorter way" refers to in the question, but I find it easier to read if the curve is specified by `out=0`, and `in=-90` angles and `looseness=` is used to to control how *curvy* you want it.

Here is an example of three different settings for `looseness=`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (1,1);
    \draw [->, red] (a) -| (b);
    %\draw [->] (a).. controls (a -| b) .. (b); % Shorter way to do this?
    \draw [black, ->] (a) to[out=0, in=-90, looseness=1.50] (b);
    \draw [orange,->] (a) to[out=0, in=-90, looseness=1.25] (b);
    \draw [blue,  ->] (a) to[out=0, in=-90, looseness=0.75] (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```