# Link A to B with straight lines (instead of curved) - MATHTIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmath

Im struggling with the options in tikz to get straight lines instead of curved lines, when im linking A to B (see picture below).

Here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\mathtikzmark}[2]{\tikz[baseline={(#1.base)},remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}
\usepackage{xparse}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\link}{ O{shorten >=4pt,shorten <=4pt} O{} O{above} m m}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, >=stealth, shift={(0,0)}]
        \draw[#1,->] (#4) to node[#3] {#2} (#5) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\hspace*{40mm}f(x) = x + \mathtikzmark{B}{3}

\fcolorbox{red}{white}{\mathtikzmark{A}{Attention: blabla}} 

\link[shorten >=1.mm,shorten <=1.mm,out=0,in=270,black]{A}{B}
\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

What im trying to get is this:

[image]

Anyone knows how to setup the options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, to draw such a line, one would use `(a) -| (b)` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/), but that wouldn't work when you're using `to` in a macro like that.

However, you could modify how `to` draws the line, by adding

```
to path={(\tikztostart) -|  (\tikztotarget)}
```

to the options of `\link`. I.e.

```
\link[shorten >=1.mm,shorten <=1.mm,black, to path={(\tikztostart) -|  (\tikztotarget)}]{A}{B}
```

[image]